# Expressjs routes with username

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, express

Im trying to use the username as route in expressjs, to view their profile.

```
app.get('/:username', function (req, res, next) {
    users.get_user(req.params.username, function (err, results) {
        if(results[0]) {
            res.render('/profile', {
                title: 'Profile',
                userinfo: results[0]
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

`users.get_user` is a function wich gets the user from the db. If it doesn't find a user it goes on to the next route. I also have a lot of other pages like `/start`, `/forum` etc. Is this an insufficient way of doing this, because theres a call to the db each time it passes through the `/:username` route. My question is, is there a better more sufficient way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try defining the more specific routes (e.g. `/start`, `/forum`) before the `/:username` route in your application.  Express matches routes in the order that you define them.

E.g. Do this:

```
app.get('/start', function(req, res, next) {...});
app.get('/forum', function(req, res, next) {...});
app.get('/:username', function(req, res, next) {...});
```

Not

```
app.get('/:username', function(req, res, next) {...});
app.get('/start', function(req, res, next) {...});
app.get('/forum', function(req, res, next) {...});
```

This way, if the user goes to `/start`, it won't hit the `/:username` route and cause a database hit.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like app.get('/:username, function(req, res, next){...}); and app.get('/:username/somethingmore', function(req, res, next){...});